Access id denied error when using sendkeys command via task scheduler
I have a small script that works just fine locally, shown below. The script opens a media file and maximizes the window of whatever application opened it.
if i am logged in and run it manually it works fine.
if i run it through a scheduleing program then I am getting "Access is denied" for sendkeys.
start 'C:\tmp\test.jpg'; Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500; Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{F11}')

What I would like to do is have the same actions happen on the same machine, but executed from a remote session. but the last portion of a remote key press doesn’t appear to be permissible using this approach.

When you run with scheduling make sure you set the account with "Run As".
